# iOS app won't let me post a question on a localized child meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, ios-app, internationalization

I tried to post a question on [Meta Stack Overflow in Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/), but the iOS app didn't let me submit it because it thought the question missed one of the required tags, as you can see here:

[image]

My post did have not just one, but two of those tags. But our tags are localized and the app didn't check the tag synonyms. On our site, "debate" is the main tag for "discussion" (which is a synonym). All our required meta tags have the original English version tag as synonyms, so maybe the app could just also check for the synonyms when validating the post.

Comment: It's a simple bug, I'm quite surprised it was overlooked.

Comment: @bob not sure overlooked, more likely they have bigger bugs to fix first, or more important new features to add.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand if this is not among their priorities, but come on, the fix should be simple enough. Probably a tweak to a SQL query, and it's done. Anyway, I'm hoping for at least a `status-planned` or `status-declined` tag with this bounty.

Comment: @bfavaretto we all do. As it stands, many bugs ([thousands](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-review+-status-reproduced)) never get any official response, even after long years. SE simply doesn't have enough developers to look at them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  There was a bad (and ugly) assumption that any site starting with `meta.` had those four specific tags.

Now the question editor will start out with no client-side required tag check and try loading the required tags when it appears.  That way, when there are issues required checking will fail off and instead be caught with server side validation.

Comment: Thank you Brian! Can't wait to test! :)